# Make android library resources private

Tags: android

I am working on an android library project. I want to make all library resources private. As per android developers documentation(https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#PrivateResources) I tried adding `<public />` in public.xml in res->values and also tried adding `<public />` in public.xml in res-public->values. Also added below code in library's build.gradle

```
sourceSets {
    main.res.srcDirs 'src/main/res', 'src/main/res-public'
}
```

But library resources are not yet private and shows up in the code completion of app module. Please give a right solution for this problem.

Gradle: 4.10.1 and Gradle plugin: 3.3.1

Comment: Didn't work for me either.

Comment: The solution didn't get until this time. Searching for the solution.

Comment: Turns out that they are private if you use the steps you mentioned. However, they are only private when you use a compiled library inside a project. But if the library and the module referencing it are both in the same project (i.e. the source code for both are present), they are not private. The docs do state that when you merge resources, the module that references the library has higher priority and will overwrite the resources used by the library - which is why you need to prefix your resources in the library with something unique.